# Parse.com WhereKey:containedIn doesn`t show any results - objectId

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, nsarray

I have UITableView with data taken from Parse.com. When I tried to filter them according to the NSArray, it does not show any results. Without the whereKey:containedIn, everything works fine. NSArray *array returns array of strings well. So the problem must be in the method containedIn, any ideas?

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    NSArray *array  = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"favorites"];
    NSLog(@"ARR:%@", array);


    if (user) {
        quer = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"bs"];
        [quer whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:array];
        [quer findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                self.itemss = [objects mutableCopy];

                NSLog(@"KOL::%lu", (unsigned long)[objects count]);
                [self.MainTable reloadData];
                if (objects.count ==0) {

                } else {

                }

            } else {

                [quer cancel];
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            }
        }];
    } else {


        NSLog(@"no");

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The array of "favorites" is an array of favorite objects when I'm sure it should be an array of objectIds. If you create an array that contains the objectIds of the favorite objects then it should work.